# regex query with or condition

Tags: mongodb

the following query should return the results that their value contains: "iffg" or "Info". however it doesn't work. what's wrong with it?

```
 { "$or" : [{ "value" : { "$regex" : ".*iffg.*", "$options" : "i" } }, { "value" : { "$regex" : ".*Info.*", "$options" : "i" } }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but try to remove the asterisk from it

`{ "$or" : [{ "value" : { "$regex" : "iffg", "$options" : "i" } }, { "value" : { "$regex" : "Info", "$options" : "i" } }] }`

you could also try using $in for your problem which looks far more cleaner

`db.collection_name.find({ "value": { "$in": [/iffg/i,/info/i] } })`

Comment: worked for me, add your regex in that array and do a query, both produce the same result and $in looks a lot cleaner anyway